# Conditioning on an event

Tags: probability

I have a very silly question about conditional probability, but have not found a good reference listing the properties of conditional probability.

I have 3 events, $A$, $B$, and $C$. They are not independent. I want to convert the expression for $P(A|B)$ into something in terms of $C$ and $C^c$ as simplified as possible, preferably containing the expressions $P(A|B,C)$ and$P(A|B,C^c)$ for which I have exact numbers.

This is what I have done:

Using Bayes first

$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$

Then I expand the numerator as follows

$\frac{P(A\cap B \cap C)}{P(B)}+\frac{P(A\cap B \cap C^c)}{P(B)}$

$\frac{P(B \cap C)P(A | B \cap C)}{P(B)}+\frac{P(B \cap C^c)P(A | B \cap C^c)}{P(B)}$

And finally

$P(C|B)P(A| B\cap C) +P(C^c|B)P(A|B\cap C^c)$

Does it make sense? Is there a simpler expression? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$A=(A\cap C) \cup (A \cap \bar{C})$, then since these two sets are disjoint we have
$P(A|B)=P(A\cap C | B) + P(A \cap \bar{C} |B)$

Similarly,
$B=(B\cap C) \cup (B \cap \bar{C})$, so

$P(A|B)=P(A|B \cap C) + P(A|B \cap \bar{C})$

Also, $P(A|B)=P(A\cap B)/P(B)$ (where $P(B) > 0$) isn't Baye's theorem, but it's the definition of conditional probability.